# What is the best way of managing multisite propagation post setup phase?

Tags: craft3, multi-site

I have a multisite setup with a pages section.
In the future we want to add additional sites but there seem to be some caveats.
When we first setup pages we set the section propagation to 'all other sites in this group'. This creates the pages we want in another site without having to recreate the content. Great :)

Once this has been done, I then change the section settings to 'only save sites they were created in'. Otherwise the content edited overwrites each site page.
However, I am trying to achieve a cookie cutter approach going forward that lets us set up a new site and then allows us to copy initial pages in the section rather than recreate the existing pages for the new site.

However there is an inherent danger in swapping propagation methods as this seems to sometimes remove content and or create failed tasks where I can't tell what craft is trying to do (maybe a bug - I'll check github later)

Is there a better way of achieving this process over time when adding sites or is best to just complete initial setup then leave and add new site and content from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like perhaps the problem you've got is that you're not making fields translatable? That would explain what you said about "Otherwise the content edited overwrites each site page ". The idea is that pages should stay set to propagate to other sections (to the group in your case), and the fields store the translation data.

Assuming that's the case, I think your problem would be solved if you didn't change that to "Only save entries to the site they were created in' and set up the fields themselves to be translatable. That would allow you to create new sites and propagate the pages.

Comment: Thanks Daryl. The fields in question are translatable. IN this instance the main field is in a matrix and it is set to translate for each language - which are the same for each site as they are all in english......So maybe the fields should be per site not per language?

Comment: Yeah if the field is set to translate per-language, but your multi-site revolves around multiple sites using the same language, then the field would be storing the same information for all of those sites. You'd need to change the field to translate per-site.